# WYSIWYG EDITOR in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Has anyone had any luck getting a WYSIWYG editor working in google apps scripts.  I have a small gas project with a form with several textarea's.  The input is saved in a scriptDb object.  I've tried using raptor editor but have had no luck.  If I place the following code in https://googledrive.com/host/folder_id/index.html it works fine.  If I try, however to put it in a script page, I get nothing.  Is it caja?

```
<div id="element-to-edit"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript"      
    src="https://raw.github.com/PANmedia/Raptor/master/packages/raptor.0deps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#element-to-edit').editor({autoEnable: true});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I haven't heard of anyone that did this. I have tried dozens of libraries available online and none work. The root of the issue is that Google Caja does not allow we get and set the caret and selection position on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Like the documentation says, u must use caja compatible libs.